# How do I draw a grid of squares the size of a fraction of the screen in opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I have the whole screen ( I may make the area smaller than the window size eventually, maybe to show scores and other relevant stats? I'm probably far from that point though ).
I want to draw a grid of squares.

The size of these squares should be a certain fraction of the size of the screen, eg. 1/2, 1/3, 1/9, etc.

I am passing an int that starts at 2, which will help me end up with a 2x2 grid of coloured squares. After certain conditions are met, this int will increment by 1, and I'll end up with a grid 3x3, 4x4 etc. ( You shouldn't worry about any actual 'game logic', I'll try to figure that out myself :P )

What I'm finding confusing, is the whole -1.0 to +1.0 coordinates opengl uses ( I hope I haven't gotten this completely wrong XD) . I have basic knowledge in SDL, and so I'm used to using 0 to 'screen height/width' coordinates. However, I don't think SDL's graphics is suitable for what I want to try, so I'm attempting to use opengl with SDL.

How might I go about figuring out the coordinates and dimensions for these squares, and actually drawing them?

( I'm not going to post any code, because I doubt what I have so far will help, but this is inside a single function that does all drawing )

extra : If any of you know how to turn coordinates that look like (x=32, y=128), for example, into opengl's floats, that might make life a whole lot easier for me, and I could figure out the coordinates, dimensions and drawing myself. (Yes, I know that opengl goes from -1.0 to +1.0 no matter the window size, so something like this wouldn't scale, but I'm perfectly fine with that)

Comment: The secret answer is, research! By doing that you will learn all the above, if you actually had read the [help/tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page, before you posted this question, would would see that this question does not fit the requirements of a question here on Stack Overflow. So go do your own research, we're not here to do it for you nor teach how things work... Then if you have an actual coding related problem, you can write a question and we will answer it, if we can.

Comment: Also, converting pixel values to more abstract coordinates is a matter of proportions, something taught in elementary mathematics.

Comment: Hmm, okay, sorry Vallentin, I guess. I sort of gave up pretty quickly trying to figure it out. Looks like I've got a little maths homework to be doing then, eh? Also, Vilin, do you know of any sites that may be able to help me? even if I can just figure out how to scale a large number to between -1 and +1, that'd be very helpful!

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Use glOrtho to get rid of your -1,+1 problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the glOrtho(0,width,height,0, 0, 1) function to set your desired dimensions.

```
void WINAPI glOrtho(
  GLdouble left,  //Left of the screen, commonly chosen as the start and set to 0
  GLdouble right, //The value for the right of the screen
  GLdouble bottom, //Same logic as above
  GLdouble top,
  GLdouble zNear,
  GLdouble zFar
);
```

So if you want your screen dimensions to be 800 wide, with the left side as the starting point, 400 high and the top your start point:

```
glOrtho(0, 800, 400, 0, 0, 1)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373965%28v=vs.85%29.aspx